# React not rendering simple component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to React thus the question. 
I'm trying to render a basic React component. This is my index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>React</title>
  </head>
  <body>

    <div id="root"></div>
    <script src="/bundle.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

This is my index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import 'babel-polyfill';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import './styles/style.css';
import  '../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import Layout from './components/Layout';

React.render(<Layout />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

This is my Layout component.

```
import React from 'react';
import {render } from 'react-dom';

class Layout extends React.Component{
  render(){
    return(
      <div className="container-fluid">
        <div className="jumbotron">
          <h1>This is home now</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default Layout;
```

This is the error I see on the console,

```
Uncaught TypeError: _react2.default.render is not a function
```

When I start the dev server, I see a blank page with nothing getting rendered. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Do you see anything in console when you load the page? warnings/errors

Comment: `render(<Layout />, document.getElementById("root"));`

Comment: What are you using this bundle this js?

Comment: You've got them mixed up - `ReactDOM.render` not `React.render`

Comment: Updated question with console output.

Comment: @AndrewLi infact that worked. thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you import the render function inside index.js from react-dom changes the way you invoke it.

```
import { render } from 'react-dom';
```

Here you just import the render method from the react-dom object. So to use it you would say

```
render(<Layout />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Comment: I would recommend addressing the possible confusion. `render` inside the component is not `ReactDOM.render`, and is not used for actually rendering to DOM - that's what `ReactDOM.render` is for

Comment: @AndrewLi Im referring to the import in the index.js file. edited to specify

Comment: I understand that, but mention there is no need for the react-dom import in the component. It may be a source of confusion